No intersection point found on line with bezier curve: (Using bezier.js by @Pomax)
Code from bezier.js works great for all other examples I've checked.
Except for this one:
const controlPoints = [450,50,300,183,150,150];
const line = { p1: {x: 400, y: 0}, p2: {x: 400, y: 100} }

const intersectionPoints = [];

    
const bezierCurve = new Bezier(x1,x2,c1,c2,y1,y2);
console.log(x1,x2,c1,c2,y1,y2);
const intersections = bezierCurve.lineIntersects(line);
if (intersections.length > 0) {
   for (let e = 0; e < intersections.length; e++) {
      let n = intersections[e],
       t = bezierCurve.get(n);
       intersectionPoints.push(t);
   }
}
console.log("Intersection Points:", intersectionPoints);

return intersectionPoints;


It returns no intersection points. Although there definitely is one at around: {x: 400, y: 90/95 }
I was expecting an intersection point between the bezier curve and the specified line.

It seems like this is a bug in the underlying bezier.js library, it will return no intersection sometimes when intersecting with a vertical line. This can be seen in this Github issue: https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs/issues/205
When you try to find the intersection with a slightly rotated line such as const line = { p1: { x: 400, y: 0 }, p2: { x: 400.01, y: 100 } }, it will work as expected.


function demo() {
  const controlPoints = [450, 50, 300, 183, 150, 150];
  const line = {
    p1: {
      x: 400,
      y: 0
    },
    p2: {
      x: 400.001,
      y: 100
    }
  };

  const intersectionPoints = [];

  const [x1, x2, c1, c2, y1, y2] = controlPoints;
  const bezierCurve = new Bezier(x1, x2, Math.floor(c1), Math.floor(c2), y1, y2);

  const intersections = bezierCurve.lineIntersects(line);
  if (intersections.length > 0) {
    for (let e = 0; e < intersections.length; e++) {
      let n = intersections[e],
        t = bezierCurve.get(n);
      intersectionPoints.push(t);
    }
  }

  console.log("Intersection Points:", intersectionPoints);
}

document.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => document.readyState === "complete" && demo());
<script type="module">
  import { Bezier } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bezier-js@6.1.4/src/bezier.min.js';
  window.Bezier = Bezier;
</script>



